# Can we add multiple ViewModel.observer() method in a single activity

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I have an activity that performs multiple  background tasks, for example:

`getJWTToken(), sendFCMTokenToServer(), isPromoAvailable(), isForcedUpgradeRequired(), fetchNewsFromServer(), sendUserLatLngToServer()`

These all are network calls, and take some time.

This is what i have done for 1 method.

```
HomeViewModel homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class); 


    homeViewModel.sendFCMTokenToServer().observe(this, isFCMSendToServer -> {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Home FCM Observer called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     });
```

Now my question is do i need to repeat the above line `homeViewModel.observer(this, )` for each method, or there is some other way for achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

I think, You should not!

You don't need to observe these changes separately.

You can do these:

- make ViewState Data model class which contains all these data (jwt token, other booleans and all)
- observe ViewModel based on this model from activity.
- In ViewModel, you can just change/update these ViewState model values using LiveData.postValue() as well.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I need to perform around 7 network operation on `MainActivity`, I need to observe all of them, So in response of each i will display some message to user.

Comment: automatically, whenever app launches, if already send, it won't perform network call.

Comment: Then, I think, you should use Call back structure here. you can use Sealed class for this 7 type of n/w calls. from ViewModel, you can return results once you get these with type and message to be displayed to the user.